# Best way parse a XML file with web scrap

Tags: node.js, reactjs, xml, puppeteer

i was trying to fetch data from an API but i was not working. If i open the URL in the browser i get this

[image]

So i thought about using puppeteer to open the URL and then parse it to a JSON format. Is that possible? What is the best way to get all that information?

Answer (score 0):

I would think cheerio for this.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
let $ = cheerio.load(xml, {xmlMode: true})
console.log($('item').get().length)
```